# ASP.Net Identity SecurityStampValidator is not called if using custom CookieAuthenticationEvents

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, cookie-authentication

Using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` (.net 7 at time of writing), the default security stamp validation is not done anymore if I use a custom `CookieAuthenticationEvents`. Configuring the `SecurityStampValidatorOptions` has no effect either.

Why is this happening and what can be done to enable the security stamp validation?

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents) 
);//this prevents securityStampValidation from occurring.

//set a small interval between validations so we can debug
builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.OnRefreshingPrincipal = c =>
{
    //breakpoint here is hit if ConfigureApplicationCookie(options.EventsType) is NOT set
    return Task.FromResult(0); 
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
```

CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents.cs is an empty class for now

```
public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior should be documented as it falls between two products.

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0#properties) says

> **Events**: The Provider may be assigned to an instance of an object created by the application at startup time. The handler calls methods on the provider which give the application control at certain points where processing is occurring. **If it is not provided a default instance is supplied which does nothing when the methods are called.**
>
> **EventsType**: If set, will be used as the service type to get the Events instance **instead of the property**.

Fine, but let's not be misleaded by the `events` definition, as it is part of the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` which is **not** the `Identity` namespace.

Instead, let's look at the code for [`IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/63c49481c2e0462c65443a9dc68ec156a46d4d55/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L54), which, among other things, does for `AddIdentity`

```
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
    };
})
```

So the cookie `Events` **is** set when adding `Identity`, and when we add our custom `options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents)`, the `Events` property is dismissed.

By looking at this code, we see that `OnValidatePrincipal` is the only event that is set, so we shouldn't have other unexpected missing functionalities. We also see that a static class is used to call the validation, so we can copy that into our `CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents`.

```
public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    public async override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        await SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync(context);
        
        //optional custom code
    }
}
```